# Limit of a specific function

Tags: limits

The function $f$ is defined over the real numbers. This table gives select values of $f$.

$
    \begin{matrix}
    x & -2.05 & -2.01 & -2.002 & -2 & -1.998 & -1.99 & -1.95 \\
    f(x) & -20 & -100 & -500 & - 4 & -4.016 & -4.08 & -4.3998 \\
    \end{matrix}
$

What's an estimate for $\lim_{x\to -2^{-}} f(x)? $

When I plot this function it looks as follows:

[image]

Would you say that left sided $lim$ is unbounded and it doesn't exist in this particular case or rather would you say that the limit approaches $-4$? And why?

Comment: Approach -2 from the left side. What does $f(x)$ seem to be doing?

Comment: Seems that $\lim_{x\to -2^-} f(x) = -\infty$.

Comment: The limit can be anything you want. The given data is not sufficient to make an estimate.

Comment: @Mircea, thanks for your comment. Could you please explain why the left sided limit is infinite? I understand (from plotting that function) that the lowest f(x) value is -500?
If I had another function that would have exactly the same values but it would started on x = -2.002 and f(x) = -500 then could I tell that the left sided limit approaches to -4?

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist because the limits from the left (which is infinite, and this in itself is enough to show the limit does not exist) is not equal to the limit on the right which is -4.

According to the table,
$f(-2-x) = -1/x$ 
and
$f(-2+x) =-4 -8x$
for $x > 0$.

Comment: Note that the question asks about $x\to -2^-$, not about $x\to -2$.

Comment: I wrote about both $-2^-$ and $-2^+$.